# Setting text in a tabular

Tags: tables

I want to make a long table (over all the page), at the moment i am using `tabular` for it, because everything in it is text.

How can i make a line with text in my `tabular` environment?
It shall be for a recipe, between the ingredients there is sometime a text.

Right now i have something like

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tabular}{rl}
60 & ab\\
   & some text here \\
   & even more text\\
40 & bc \\
\end{tabular}
\]
\end{document}
```

I would prefer a formatting like

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
60 &\ ab
\intertext{some text and even more text here}
40 &\ bc\\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your question seems a bit vague -- please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what you have done so far.

Comment: Try to sketch what you want in Excel for example, then put the image in your post, so people can help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`\multicolumn`](http://www.tug.org/tutorials/latex2e/$5cmulticolumn.html) and the [`array`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) package, one way to achieve what you want is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
60 & ab\\  
\multicolumn{2}{p{1cm}}{some text and even more text here some text and even more text here some text and even more text here}\\
40 & bc
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

You can change the value `1cm` to what works better to you.

Comment: my text is to long for a single line how can i tell $\LaTeX$ to break it inside a multicolumn?

Comment: @DominicMichaelis leo gave you the proper solution. His `p@{1cm}` creates a 1cm wide column that lets you typeset paragraphs with proper line breaking. If you need a wider column, just change the size.